# RecyclerView OnClick Listener returning error

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am struggling to find a way of sending the selected recipe_name in a putExtra intent from a recyclerView adapter. With what I've tried I get this error.

> error: cannot find symbol
> intent.putExtra("NAME", categoryList.getAdapterPosition().getRecipe_name());
> ^   symbol:   method getAdapterPosition()   location: variable categoryList of type
> List

This is the snippet I've tried so far amongst others

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Recipe.class);
        intent.putExtra("NAME", categoryList.getAdapterPosition().getRecipe_name());
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
```

**Full Adapter Code**

```
public class RecipeCategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecipeCategoryAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Category> categoryList;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private com.stu54259.plan2cook.RecipeCategoryAdapter.ItemClickListener mClickListener;

    // data is passed into the constructor
    RecipeCategoryAdapter(Context context, List<Category> data) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.categoryList = data;
    }

    // inflates the row layout from xml when needed
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_recipe, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

/**
 * Called by RecyclerView to display the data at the specified position. This method should
 * update the contents of the {@link ViewHolder#itemView} to reflect the item at the given
 * position.
 * <p>
 * Note that unlike {@link ListView}, RecyclerView will not call this method
 * again if the position of the item changes in the data set unless the item itself is
 * invalidated or the new position cannot be determined. For this reason, you should only
 * use the <code>position</code> parameter while acquiring the related data item inside
 * this method and should not keep a copy of it. If you need the position of an item later
 * on (e.g. in a click listener), use {@link ViewHolder#getAdapterPosition()} which will
 * have the updated adapter position.
 * <p>
 * Override {@link #onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder, int, List)} instead if Adapter can
 * handle efficient partial bind.
 *
 * @param holder   The ViewHolder which should be updated to represent the contents of the
 *                 item at the given position in the data set.
 * @param position The position of the item within the adapter's data set.
 */
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.myTextView1.setText(categoryList.get(position).getRecipe_name());
    holder.myTextView2.setText(categoryList.get(position).getCategory_name());
    holder.imgImage.setImageResource(categoryList.get(position).getImage());

}


    // total number of rows
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categoryList.size();
    }


    // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView myTextView1;
        TextView myTextView2;
        ImageView imgImage;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            myTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            myTextView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCategory);
            imgImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgImage);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);


        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Recipe.class);
            intent.putExtra("NAME", categoryList.getAdapterPosition().getRecipe_name());
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    }


    // allows clicks events to be caught
    void setClickListener(RecipeCategoryAdapter.ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the data to be sent into another activity using intent, you can just do this in view holder class.

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView myTextView1;
    TextView myTextView2;
    ImageView imgImage;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        myTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        myTextView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCategory);
        imgImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgImage);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Your_activity);
                intent.putExtra("recipe_name", myTextView1.gettext().toString); //you used recipe name with this id (myTextView1) so.
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can also implement the above click listener code in onbindview as well. But when you click any particular item it checks all the viewholders, hence to overcome that we can do that in view holder class as above. Please let me know if it works. And accept the answer if it's working for you.

Comment: I've tried that and get this error.No candidates found for method call categoryList.getAdapterPosition().

Comment: There is an issue in getting that position @RevansArden, But the method is correct. So basically you want the position of that item?

Comment: So basically the adapter displays a cardview of all recipes within a particular category and then on click of a recipe I want it to go to that recipe, therefore stating a new activity intent and putExtra of the recipe name.

Comment: Yeah. If you want the data in a new activity then you don't need the listeners actually. The listener in the adapter is mostly used to send the position of the data to the activity in which we implemented the adapter. @RevansArden

Comment: So how would I do this then, I'm confused?

Comment: Please check the last Updated snippet i added. you can easily do with just itemview.setonclicklistener @RevansArden

Answer (score 0):

**Then use in this way**

```
   @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder (@NonNull ViewHolder holder,int position){
            holder.myTextView1.setText(categoryList.get(position).getRecipe_name());
            holder.myTextView2.setText(categoryList.get(position).getCategory_name());
            holder.imgImage.setImageResource(categoryList.get(position).getImage());
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    startActivity(new Intent(ShiftHistory.this, Recipe.class)
                            .putExtra("NAME", categoryList.get(position).getRecipe_name()));
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I can't seem to work out how to implement this solution in my problem, especially as I'm not familiar with koitlin